# Firefox adds `-#` to files when dragging attachments from Outlook

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook

I've found that, when dragging an attachment from Outlook into Firefox, it adds a `-1` `-2` `-etc` suffix to the file. This does not happen in Chrome and seems to only happen with Outlook attachments, dragging files from Explorer don't have the issue. This is on Firefox 119.0.1 and Outlook 2308, I made a jsfiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/98xb4vgn/

Here's what my test attachment looks like, I drag from this into Firefox:
[image]

And the jsfiddle shows an alert with the uploaded file name:
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test in Edge and Outlook client, i got the same result. I'm afraid that it's the expected behavior of your browser.

[image]

> And the jsfiddle shows an alert with the file name:

For this, it's suggested that you could refer to the related settings in Firefox: [Download protection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-find-and-manage-downloaded-files-firefox#:%7E:text=in%20Firefox.-,Download%20protection,-Before%20beginning%20a).

If the above doesn't help, you'd better to contact the support of Firefox for more professional suggestions.

Comment: That looks awfully like how Windows renames files when there's a collision in your downloads folder. This is specifically with uploads: the uploaded file has a different name than what was actually dragged from Outlook

Comment: Where did you want to upload?

Comment: The jsfiddle has a drop zone that `alert`s the file's name that would have been uploaded.